# $resource PATCH request return HTTP 415

Tags: spring-mvc, angularjs

I defined a $resource and added a PATCH method:

```js
myapp.factory( 'Monitoring', function($resource) {
   return $resource('/webapp/network/v1/cronjobs/:id/:action', { id: '@id' }, {
       status: { method: 'PATCH', params:{id:"@id", action: 'status'}}
   }
   );
});
```

When calling the URL I get `PATCH http://localhost:8080/webapp/network/v1/cronjobs/1/status 415 (Unsupported Media Type)`

```js
    changeStatus: function(id, status) {
        var m = new Monitoring({id:id});
        m.status = status;
        m.$status();
    }
```

My backend is Spring

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/status", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public ResponseEntity<Void> patchStatus(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
        @RequestBody String status) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the `Content-Type` header:

```
status: { method: 'PATCH', headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, params:{id:"@id", action: 'status'}}
```

It works but is it the correct way?